# Slow user profile page load after having earned several bounties

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, profile-page, performance

I am noticing that [the](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=bounties&sort=earned) [list](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov?tab=bounties&sort=earned) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell?tab=bounties&sort=earned) [earned](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc?tab=bounties&sort=earned) [bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant?tab=bounties&sort=earned) loads **noticeably** slower when the user has more than 10ish bounties! The same slowness is noticed by activating the [`earned` link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yhjhj.png) on the list of bounties in the Summary tab. The effect can be seen whether *logged in or not*.

Here's some visual feedback from Chrome's Developer Tools as to the differences between one and the other.

***Without* showing earned bounties:**
[image: Profile speed without showing earned bounties]

***Showing* earned bounties:**
[image: Profile speed showing earned bounties]

---

As you can see, there's a whopping **4 seconds difference** during page request! I don't think this is critical, but it seems like it may be putting additional stress somewhere (other than cache).

---

**UPDATE 2013-05-13:** It's happening again. In contrast, the [same](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/135201/nick-craver?tab=bounties&sort=earned) [does](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9?tab=bounties&sort=earned) [**not**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=bounties&sort=earned) [happen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/17174/sam-saffron?tab=bounties&sort=earned) [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell?tab=bounties&sort=earned) on MSO.

Here's a new screenshot:

[image: Reoccurring Profile Speed Issues]

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, are you still seeing slowness? If so it could be a non-mod view of the query in which case I need to dig deeper.

Comment: @Nick It looks like somebody fixed something. It's working blazingly fast now. It had been working slow for upwards of two weeks (don't know about before that), if I recall correctly. There must've been some update on the earned bounties query recently.

Comment: nope nothing there, may have been a bad plan for that I cleared out with a batch a few days ago though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was likely a bad query plan, one of several nuked from the plan cache over the past few days - if the issue returns let me know and I'll take another look at how the parameterization is behaving here.

Comment: Sounds like a plan! I'll add a comment to this answer if I see it again.

Comment: It's happening again. I've also unmarked your answer to try to draw your attention. =)

Comment: I see it too, with for example this user: http://stackoverflow.com/users/712765/old-pro?tab=bounties&sort=earned (takes up to 6sec to load)

Comment: @cheesemacfly try now...I've nuked that plan from cache and noted what needs changing, but nuking it is the best I can do from an ipad on a plane.  I'll make the necessary query option changes once I land.

Comment: @NickCraver It's still happening.

Comment: @NickCraver still happening...sorry

Comment: @NickCraver Any resolution to this?

Comment: @Jesse - sorry, we're all over the place at google i/o this week...can you give it a go now? I've pushed a query option change that should prevent the bad plan in the future

Comment: @NickCraver No worries. It's still slow, however.

Comment: @Jesse which URL are you trying? I'm unable to get over a 100ms page load here no matter who I hit, logged in or our (moderators get a different query)

Comment: @NickCraver I'm testing the original set in the question: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=bounties&sort=earned) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov?tab=bounties&sort=earned) [3](http://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell?tab=bounties&sort=earned) [4](http://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc?tab=bounties&sort=earned) [5](http://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant?tab=bounties&sort=earned). I've even tried different connections (direct and proxy). Can I do anything differently that will yield better logging/stats to help you?

Comment: @NickCraver For what it's worth - it's working fast again. Hopefully you found the issue.

Comment: @NickCraver Works fast again here too!